# IFrame in content script. How to communicate with main.js?

Tags: iframe, fancybox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

My Firefox add-on opens Fancybox (type: "iframe") from a content script (page-mod). In the Fancybox I show my own HTML page (*my_fancybox_stuff.html*) that is located in my own server.

Now, from the `my_fancybox_stuff.js` (javascript of *my_fancybox_stuff.html*), can I send a message to the add-on's `main.js`? Or to the content script that opened the Fancybox?

I was hoping the global 'self' object to be accessible from my_fancybox_stuff.js as it is accessible from the content script that opened the Fancybox.

I am interested to hear about any potential workarounds to get this done.

In Chrome extension this is trivial. In `my_fancybox_stuff.js` I can call `chrome.extension.sendMessage()` and it works.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Adding some code to clarify my case. Simplified the code to save folks' time on reading it. This is simple as hello world.

From the contents_scipt.js (injected with page-mod) I call:

```
$.fancybox.open(
    {
    // Some irrelevant Fancybox options hidden for clarity
    href:"http://www.mysite.com/my_fancybox_stuff.html
    type: 'iframe'
    }
);
```

my_fancybox_stuff.html would look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/my_fancybox_stuff.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my-wrapper">
  <div id="my-form-div">
    <form id="my-form" action="#">
      <div>
        <div><p>Name</p></div>
        <div><input id="fullname" type="text" name="fullname" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div><p><a id="my-button" href="#">Press this</a></p></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

In my_fancybox_stuff.js, when button ("my_button") is pressed, I want to send out a message containing the value of the input field ("fullname") and listen it in content_script.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your *my_fancybox_stuff.js* can communicate with your add-on's content script using `postMessage ()`.

See [the documentation and examples at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

Comment: Thanks Brock! I actually was reading about window.postMessage before sending the question, and I kept reading after your answer. I'm just such a dummy with any web stuff that I'm all confused with how to implement it in my case. I mean, what should be 'window' in my window.postMessage when I want to listen the message in the (page-mod initiated) content script? Maybe I should add some code in my question.

Comment: Right. I edited the question and added some simplified code to clarify my case.

Comment: I finally got it working. I needed to simply call window.parent.postMessage in my_fancybox_stuff.js. In content_script I called addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false) and defined receiveMessage callback function. "window.parent" was the decisive part for me. Brock, thanks for your crucial help. Accepting your answer.