# Get content of some file in Firefox SDK main.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So I'm developing a Firefox addon that adds a bit of HTML to the DOM of any webpage.

The idea here is that I'm using a file called `template.html` as a template, that is located in the `data` folder inside the addon folder.
Next, I would like to use the contents of that `template.html` file inside a variable, so that I can append it to the DOM.

**myAddon/data/template.html:**

```
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

**myAddon/lib/main.js:**

```
var template = ... // This is where I want to fetch the contents of template.html.

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*", // Apply script at any page
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.11.2.min.js"), data.url("main.js")], // Include jQuery and myAddon/data/main.js
    onAttach: function(worker){ // when these files are attached, send the content of the html-file to the script.
        worker.port.emit("sendTemplate", template);
    }
});
```

**myAddon/data/main.js**

```
self.port.on("sendTemplate", function(template){
    // var template should be <div>{{test}}</div>
}
```

I've found "Panel" in the SDK, but I do not want to show the HTML-file as a panel.

Secondly, I've tried to just send the resource URL of template.html and then to `$.get(templateURL)` in `myAddon/data/main.js`, but that did not work because Firefox does not allow a `resource://`-file to be `$.get()`'d.

How can I make sure that the content of an HTML-file that is saved into the addon's data folder is fetched as a string and put into a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### myAddon/lib/main.js:

```
var template = require("sdk/self").data.load("template.html"); // This is where I want to fetch the contents of template.html.

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*", // Apply script at any page
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.11.2.min.js"), data.url("main.js")], // Include jQuery and myAddon/data/main.js
    contentScriptOptions: {
      template: template
    }
});
```

### myAddon/data/main.js

```
var template = self.options.template;
```

Comment: I have really spent an hour trying to find it in the documentation, but I couldn't find it. Thanks a lot, works like a charm!

Comment: this works fine for images, scripts and styles. but because of CPS, you need to use low level API to fill an iframe with a local html file in most websites.